# In my Bootstrap/Rails app, Which file do I add my Custom navbar CSS to?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I have got some Bootstrap functionality up and running on my app. So far so good. I know that the 2 defaults colors for the navbar are black and white,using navbar-default and navbar-inverse. I am trying to add the navbar color change CSS to the assets/stlyesheets/application.css file, but  not having any luck. the color im changing it to is green. ( an irrigation system website. Green for grass, yay)

this is what my application.css file currently looks like.

```
 /*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the 
 files listed below
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets 
 /stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */

 .navbar-default {
     background-color: #33FF33;
     border-color: #E7E7E7;
 }
```

Comment: You can try use `!important` .. `.navbar-default { background-color: #33FF33 !important; border-color: #e7e7e7 !important; }`

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file under `app/assets/stylesheets`, add your custom styles to the file, then include it in `application.css.scss`.

```
@import custom_navbar.css.scss;
```

You will want to change `application.css` to `application.css.scss` and remove the comments entirely. You will then import the files you want using the `@import` directive.

Note that this somewhat breaks away from convention, but it might work for your purposes. You can read more about [structuring SASS projects](http://thesassway.com/beginner/how-to-structure-a-sass-project) on the SASS blog.

Comment: by new file, do you mean .css or .css.scss ? Using my custom style i used, how should this file look ?

Comment: It depends. `.css` or `.scss` will work. `.scss` is the SASS preprocessor. It lets you use variables and functions to compile your CSS. If you want to use SCSS, follow the instructions in my answer. The file will look exactly the same. Just make sure you import it after you import bootstrap, otherwise Bootstrap will overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) gem (you should), the right way to do this, is to set the bootstrap variables, in your application.css.scss, before including bootstrap:

```
$navbar-default-bg: #33FF33;
$navbar-default-border: #E7E7E7;

@import "bootstrap";
```